# React Router not redirecting after user was logged in

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have small problem with React Router and redirecting. After i have created a admin protected route, I want the user to be redirected to "user dashboard" after login. But my issue is that redirect is not working. 
All is happening like this:

My Navigation componente, but this one i think is okay:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import { signOut, isAuthUser } from '../../../utils/utils';

const isActive = (history, path) => {
  if (history.location.pathname === path) {
    return { color: '#ff9900' };
  } else {
    return { color: '#ffffff' };
  }
};

const Navigation = ({ history }) => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul className='nav nav-tabs bg-primary'>
        <li className='nav-item'>
          <Link className='nav-link' style={isActive(history, '/')} to='/'>
            Home
          </Link>
          <Link
            className='nav-link'
            style={isActive(history, '/user/dashboard')}
            to='/user/dashboard'
          >
            Dashboard
          </Link>
          {!isAuthUser() && (
            <div>
              <Link
                className='nav-link'
                style={isActive(history, '/signup')}
                to='/signup'
              >
                Signup
              </Link>
              <Link
                className='nav-link'
                style={isActive(history, '/signin')}
                to='/signin'
              >
                Signin
              </Link>
            </div>
          )}
          {isAuthUser() && (
            <Link
              className='nav-link'
              style={isActive(history, '/signout')}
              onClick={() => signOut()}
              to='/'
            >
              Sign Out
            </Link>
          )}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Navigation);
```

My app.js with Routes

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import MainLayout from '../src/components/layout/MainLayout/MainLayout';
import Signup from './components/views/Signup/Signup';
import Signin from './components/views/Signin/Signin';
import Home from './components/views/Home/Home';
import PrivateRoute from './components/common/ProvateRoute/PrivateRoute';
import UserDashboard from './components/views/UserDashboard/UserDashboard';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <MainLayout>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route exact path='/signin' component={Signin} />
          <Route exact path='/signup' component={Signup} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path='/user/dashboard' component={UserDashboard} />
        </Switch>
      </MainLayout>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My utils.js with some helper functions

```
export const signOut = () => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    localStorage.removeItem('jwt');
    return fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/signout', { method: 'GET' }).then(res => {
      console.log('signout', res);
    });
  }
};

export const authenticateUser = data => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    localStorage.setItem('jwt', JSON.stringify(data));
  }
};

//check if user is auth and there is jwt item in localstorage. menu render
export const isAuthUser = () => {
  if (typeof window == 'undefined') {
    return false;
  }
  if (localStorage.getItem('jwt')) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jwt'));
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

So those looks okay in my opinion, but still i decided to post those here.

As all things that are most related are in my tow files: UserDashboard and Signin

My Signin.js looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

import Layout from '../../layout/Layout/Layout';
import { authenticateUser, isAuthUser } from '../../../utils/utils';

class Signin extends Component {
  state = {
    formData: {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    },
    userRedirect: false,
  };

  onChange = e => {
    const { formData } = this.state;
    //assign form data to new variable
    let newFormData = { ...formData };
    newFormData[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      formData: newFormData,
    });
  };

  signIn = user => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:8000/api/signin', user, config)
      .then(res => authenticateUser(res.data));
    this.setState({
      formData: { email: '', password: '' },
      userRedirect: true,
    });
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    const { password, email } = this.state.formData;
    e.preventDefault();
    this.signIn({ email, password });
  };

  signInForm = (email, password) => (
    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
      <div className='form-group'>
        <label className='text-muted'>Email</label>
        <input
          type='email'
          name='email'
          value={email}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          className='form-control'
        ></input>
      </div>
      <div className='form-group'>
        <label className='text-muted'>Password</label>
        <input
          type='password'
          name='password'
          minLength='6'
          value={password}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          className='form-control'
        ></input>
      </div>
      <button className='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );

  redirecUser = () => {
    const { userRedirect } = this.state;
    const { user } = isAuthUser();

    if (userRedirect === true) {
      if (user && user.role === 1) {
        return <Redirect to='/admin/dashboard' />;
      } else {
        return <Redirect to='/user/dashboard' />;
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { email, password } = this.state.formData;

    return (
      <Layout
        title='Signin'
        description='Login to your account'
        className='container col-md-8 offset-md-2'
      >
        {this.signInForm(email, password)}
        {this.redirecUser()}
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

export default Signin;
```

Here I am rendering all with `signInForm` and passing all data that i want with `signIn()`. From this i get user data: _id, email, password, role and token. This is sent to local storage.

Based on that what i get i want admin dashboard or user dashboard.
I have now olny user Dashboard

```
import React from 'react';
import { isAuthUser } from '../../../utils/utils';

import Layout from '../../layout/Layout/Layout';

const UserDashboard = () => {
  const {
    payload: {
      user: { name, email, role },
    },
  } = isAuthUser();

  return (
    <Layout
      title='User Dashboard'
      description={`Wlecome ${name}`}
      className='container col-md-8 offset-md-2'
    >
      <div className='card mb-5'>
        <h3 className='card-header'>User information</h3>
        <ul className='list-group'>
          <li className='list-group-item'>{name}</li>
          <li className='list-group-item'>{email}</li>
          <li className='list-group-item'>
            {role === 1 ? 'Admin' : 'Registered User'}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className='card'>
        <h3 className='card-header'>Purchase history</h3>
        <ul className='list-group'>
          <li className='list-group-item'>History</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default UserDashboard;
```

I have created PrivateRoute component based on documentation

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { isAuthUser } from '../../../utils/utils';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      isAuthUser() ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/signin', state: { from: props.location } }} />
      )
    }
  />
);

export default PrivateRoute;
```

I do get all data in local storage, but after signin user is not redirected

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to redirect from a function in your Signin.js try using history api.

```
this.props.history.push('/admin/dashboard')
```

instead of

```
<Redirect to='/admin/dashboard' />;
```

Comment: not sure why, but isAuthuser is not passing user values

Comment: You mean you have got the issue `const { user } = isAuthUser();` here? is it even going inside loop to call redirect?

Comment: this is getting user from local storage `export const isAuthUser = () => {
  if (typeof window == 'undefined') {
    return false;
  }
  if (localStorage.getItem('jwt')) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jwt'));
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};` but onot sure why, when I am trying to use `user` then it is not getting any values